# Tie Breaking in Final Round of Ranked Choice Vote

Tags: democracy, voting, voting-systems

Been thinking about RCV a lot because Virginia (where I live) may pass a bill to use it in state elections. Also been thinking about ties in elections because one of the delegate districts here is tied and is going to be decided by a straw drawing, no joke.

I want to know if in the final round of RCV if say two remaining candidates both get exactly the same number of votes after the rest of the candidates are eliminated if there is a better way than a coin toss to decide? Could you consider the previous round to see which of those two candidates had the most votes at that point? Would that be fair? I want to hear folks thoughts and if y'all have found any sources for this because I can't.

Answer (score 3):

The act that addresses the subject states as follows ([Source](http://lis.virginia.gov/cgi-bin/legp604.exe?171+ful+HB2315+pdf)):

> Any ties that could affect the outcome of the election shall be resolved in accordance with §24.2-674.

It is worth noting that this affects not only a tie amongst the final two, but also a tie among the bottom two in any count where one will advance and the other will not.

Now this bill does not amend §24.2-674 in any way.  As per the [current law](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title24.2/chapter6/section24.2-674/), this is dealt with by drawing lots.

You suggested looking at the results of a previous round, however it's worth remembering that this is an instant runoff election.  That means that each count after the first should be treated as a runoff, and thus be independent of the counts before it.

Comment: Idk what law you are talking about.... I'm talking in hypotheticals as in if I were going to write a bill or procedure from scratch how should I determine the winner if in the final round two candidates are tied.

Comment: That's really a question of opinion, which will be off topic on Politics.se.